# Navigation Component with Login / Register / Home flow

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to use the new Navigation Component for my next application but I can't quite wrap my head around the overall flow of navigation.
The Android team recommends a single activity as an entry point. They also suggest that conditional elements like a login / register should not be the entry point.
But then how do you display the login and register buttons if the entry screen is supposed to be the home screen?

Another idea is to use a Splash screen, have the logic there to determine if the user is already logged in, if so go to the home screen, if not show the login / register screen(s).

My other issue is with the single activity. My home screen would need to be a screen with a Bottom Navigation.

How do you tie all of this the "right way"? Do I need to have a separate navigation graph for the Home view, with the Bottom Navigation and the many screens that will flow from there?

All the examples I have found have been very straightforward, and the few I have seen with a Splash screen splitting into Home and Login have a very simple Home fragment, which in my case would be . more complex with the Bottom Nav.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, you hide the bottom navigation in the login and popup the homepage when you navigate to the login page so the user would not be able to go back to the splash screen

1-you can hide the bottom naviagtion bar in the login fragment like this

```
val toolbar = activity!!.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
val bottombar = activity!!.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
        toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
        bottombar.visibility = View.GONE
```

2- popup the splash fragment when you navigate to the login page

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Hopefully it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Simple example =

Single activity, Multi fragment with bottom navigation bar and with Android Navigation comp.

Plan:

- Show a splash screen with a timer like 3000 milis.
- End of the milis navigate the user to login screen if already logged (check it on splash) navigate user to home screen
- Now you can show a bottom nav. bar. For example "Home" "News"
- You can handle backPresses in navigation. Handle for home (Disable to returning splash)

That's all folks!

Comment: I would definitely not use a timer anywhere, that would be a bad idea, since all you need is to actually check for login credentials.
But my problem is more, what do you land on? 
The Splash fragment? The android team was saying not to use conditional entry points, but in that case I'm not sure where you would check for login credentials.
Later on, is it fine to have the whole bottom nav, plus a nav drawer, all of it sitting in a fragment?

Comment: Timer just for splash screen. If you don't want, you can delete it. You can make login screen like that : When user login the app, save them on Shared Preferences and in splash screen check it, or another system like that?

Later on, put bottom nav,toolbar,drawer on activity, and then add a fragment to main_activity. Just switch the fragments.